# Is there a way to validate method parameters on spring-data-rest repository methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

For instance, I have a repository class like this.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer> {

  Optional<Foo> findByBarId(@Param("barId") Integer barId);

}
```

This generates a search endpoint with path `http://hostname/foo/search/findByBarId{?fooId}`

When I access this URL without any parameters, I get a `404` which I i think is okay.

However, I would rather send a 400 for this type or errors as my business would definitely need a parameter for this API.

I tried using `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`

```
Optional<Foo> findByBarId(@Param("barId") @NotNull Integer barId);
```

as well as `@org.springframework.lang.NonNull`

```
Optional<Foo> findByBarId(@Param("barId") @NonNull Integer barId);
```

Both annotations did not work. Of Course it doesn't work because these annotations by itself is just meta information which is not being taken into account by spring-framework.

The documentation didn't have anything showcased for parameter validation behaviour. (They only speak about entity lifecycle [validation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/validation.adoc))

Is there any straightforward way I can achieve such behaviour?

I use `spring-boot` 2.0.4 if that helps.

Comment: I guess I will have to raise a feature request for `spring-data-rest` project

Answer (score -1):

You can write a **RepositoryRestController** to run specific business to customize your endpoints.

Here is an example for your case, you can customize it as well :

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class FooController {

    FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Autowired
    public FooController(FooRepository fooRepository) {
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/foo")
    public ResponseEntity getfoo(@RequestParam("barId") Optional<Integer> barId) {
        if (!barId.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }

        Optional<Foo> foo = fooRepository.findByBarId(barId.get());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to do it the old-school way. And I was specific to what I was asking. I want to do it the spring-data-rest way, (with no controller code)  And to point out, the optional parameter and conditional check is unnecessary in your code as it is default behaviour for spring-mvc to check for `RequestParam`s unless you say `required=false` in the annotation definition.

Comment: You want to return 400 if parameter is null, if you don't put Optional<> what happens did you test it? I got http 500 in server-side in that case. And also you don't specify you don't want to use controller, so what was the reason of down vote?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that spring is taking care of 400 error status if the @RequestParam is not found in the request for `@RestController` you dont have to check for them in your method body and you dont have to declare your parameters optional.And for the downvote, I am asking for a spring data rest based solution where I dont want to write controller methods.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but RepositoryRestController is in package org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc. So does not it is a "spring data rest based solution" ? And I do it optional because you want to check it manuelly (may be I don't understand your question exactly), I can put required=false but it does not return 400. And if you don't put required=false, when you send a request to /foo without param it will return 500 and not 400.

Comment: Even though your argument seem valid, it is just a glorified mvc @Controller where I get to manage the status/response. And the reason why I dont call your code not spring-data-rest way is due to the lack of information on resource links self refs.(which is again more code for me to write and maintain). I hope that clarifies what I am trying to ask.